# Обертка (тунелирование ?) запросов на HTTP для передачи на HTTPS

Tags: http, https, tunnel

Доброго времени суток. Суть задачи:
Старая версия некоего ПО работает только по HTTP. Более современная версия того же ПО умеет только по HTTPS. Сразу отключить старую у сотни пользователей не получается. Нужно что-то вроде мини-сервера, способного принимать запросы к себе на порт 80 и отправлять на внешний ресурс на порт 443, с последующим диалогом разумеется. 
stunnel, так понимаю, такого не умеет.
NGINX и Apache делают простой редирект с подменой URL'а.
Прокси-серверы? Но который? Или самому создавать? - тогда на чем? Встречал нерабочие примеры на Node.js и python.

В любом случае, спасибо.

Comment: [Это](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/) не то?

Comment: Увы, нет. Повторюсь, простой апстрим NGINX "заменяет url в адресной строке браузера". А надо, чтобы условная программа клиент, хоть браузер, хоть 1С , хоть что угодно, видела один единственный url постоянно. И думала, что обращается на него по порту 80. Или любому другому, но с протоколом HTTP.